# How to determine all views which are overlapping with given view?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to determine all views (rectangles) which are overlapping given view. (Idea is to get visible area of givenView)

```
public List<Rect> getOverlappingViewsForGivenView(View givenView)
{
  //return overlapping rectangles
}
```

I can use `getGlobalVisibleRect` to get Visible area but it considers overlaps only by parent elements. I tried above getGlobalVisibleRect eg. View covered by it's parent ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can get with `getX()`and `getY()` the position of your view on screen. If it is in a scroll view You might want to check if it is "on screen" and such.

With the given bounds you would get the root view (e.g. calling `getParent()`), and iterate over the children with `getChildCount()`and `getChildAt(int)`.

That's the general Idea. Depending on your layout hierarchy this can get very easy or very tricky.

Comment: I think, there can be children from different branch which can cause this overlap,  We can't use getParent(), we need to consider other views too.

Comment: You can call get parent until you're at the root. You can then descend again ;)

Comment: Yup, that's one option, not sure how complicated that will become, my method is generic and it's part of third party library